# Django easy retrieval of items in a Many-to-many relationship model

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a many-to-many relationship with these entities:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    videos = models.ManyToManyField("Video")

class Video(models.Model):
    pass
```

I need a third model to replace the M2M relationship with a foreign key to this couple of entities without the actual need to modify the way we access and query the playlist videos `PlayList().videos`, which would take us to a code refactoring hell.

This is the third relationship:

```
class PlaylistVideos(models.Model):
    playlist = models.ForeignKey('PlayList') 
    video = models.ForeignKey('Video')
    new_field = models.IntegerField()
    #... other stuff
```

Summarizing, I would like something like an alias attribute for easy access the videos of a particular playlist, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a through table:

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    videos = models.ManyToManyField("Video", through="PlaylistVideos")
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). You can still access the videos as `playlist.videos` but it will generate multiple queries and will thus be less efficient than before. This is discussed in [How do I make Django ManyToMany 'through' queries more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255700/how-do-i-make-django-manytomany-through-queries-more-efficient). You will need to decide if the extra queries will significantly impact your application. As discussed in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), you will not be able to add new videos to a playlist without using the `PlaylistVideos` model, since you will need to specify a value for `new_field`.